# CKEditor Scrolls to Top in Firefox when Paragraph Format Changed

Tags: asp.net, firefox, ckeditor

I have searched the CKEditor forum for this issue, but did not find it.

I am using CKEditor 4.5.3 with ASP.NET Web Forms (.NET Framework 4.6). Firefox version is 46.0.1. The problem does not appear in Chrome or Internet Explorer. Also, the problem does not appear in the official demo, even in Firefox.

There is only one instance of CKEditor on the page. I am using it to edit a job description. The job description is about three times longer than the height of the CKEditor window. To duplicate the bug, I scroll down to the bottom of the job description and select some text. I then use a dropdown on the CKEditor toolbar to change the paragraph format. For example, I might choose "Heading 2". As soon as I change the paragraph format, CKEditor immediately scrolls to the top of the job description, and the altered paragraph disappears below the bottom of the window. I must then scroll back down to the paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

I just encountered this problem in Firefox. We're using custom CSS and it turns out `body {height: 100%;}` was the culprit.

See 
[CKeditor jumps to top with certain css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34110733/ckeditor-jumps-to-top-with-certain-css)
and 
https://www.drupal.org/node/1096164#comment-4603964